# node mysql connects to one ip address but not another

Tags: node-mysql

The following connection works using mysql node

```
// create mysql connection
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'ip-208-109-35-193.ip.secureserver.net',
  user: 'myusr',
  password: 'mypass',
  database : 'admin_ad',
  port: '3306'
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Failed to connect MySQL.');
    console.error(err);
    return;
}
});
```

However when I try another host such as:

```
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '64.64.64.64',
  user: 'myusr',
  password: 'mypass',
  database : 'admin_ad',
  port: '3306'
});
```

The connection does NOT work.  I tried these exact same credentials in a Sequel application locally (Sequel Ace) on mac and it works I get a connection.
Does node mysql add somethign to the host or is there some type of protection set that needs to be undone? I have no idea why the same exact credentials that work on an application don't work on node mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging into this I found that a server ip doesn't just "work".  In example my hosting company has my server on a host named: "w4tr-gg7p.accessdomain.com" where the ip is 64.64.64.64.  On a client such as Sequel Ace the ip works just fine.  However on node mysql this does not work:

```
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '64.64.64.64',
  user: 'myusr',
  password: 'mypass',
  database : 'admin_ad',
  port: '3306'
});
```

Change the host to `"w4tr-gg7p.accessdomain.com"`
This is very confusing since in the node mysql documentation it always references the ip.  I hope this helps someone that encounters this issue.